# Why is my cors headers not matching even when they are the same?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ajax, cors, passport.js

I am using passport js with REACT and during fetching  the  logged in user-data the cors header of fetch isnt matching even though they are the same.

this is where i am sending fetch to
http://localhost:3001/profilebuilder

And address I am fetching from
http://localhost:5000/auth/login/success

```
app.use(
  cors({
    origin: 'http://localhost:3001/profilebuilder',
    methods: "GET,POST,PUT,DELETE",
    credentials: true,
  })
);
app.listen("5000", () => {
  console.log("Server is running!");
});
```

this is the client code

```
 fetch("http://localhost:5000/auth/login/success", {
          method: "GET",
          credentials: "include",
          headers: {
            Accept: "application/json",
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": true,
          },
        })
          .then((response) => {
            if (response.status === 200) return response.json();
            throw new Error("authentication has been failed!");
          })
          .then((resObject) => {
            setProfile(resObject.user);
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
          });
```

I am getting  this error

```
Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:5000/auth/login/success' 
from origin 'http://localhost:3001' has been blocked by CORS 
policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control
 check: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'http://localhost:3001/profilebuilder' 
that is not equal to the supplied origin. Have the server 
send the header with a
valid value, or, if an opaque response serves your needs,
 set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

Comment: To complement Heiko's answer: no point in adding an `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` header to your request, as this is a _response_ header.

Answer (score 0):

You set `http://localhost:3001/profilebuilder` as `origin` header, but this is not a valid origin. The [origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Origin) ends after the hostname or port, so it should be

```
origin: 'http://localhost:3001'
```

Comment: hey man it worked.Thanks.Can u upvote my question ?